# Comparison of arrays and calculation

Tags: python, arrays, list, comparison, compare

I have 3 lists

```
r = [0.105, 0.111, 0.218, 0.225, 0.332, 0.440, 0.548, 0.656, 0.865, 1.75]
ro = [850, 856, 844, 830, 787, 826, 764, 773, 781, 748]
new_r = [0.25672, 0.39602, 0.55907, 0.65756, 0.77467, 0.93619]
```

length of `r` and `ro` are always same, but `len(new_r)` is always less than that of `r` and `ro`.
I want to calculate

```
(r[i+1] -r[i])**3*ro[i+1]
```

for all `r[i]`s which are less than first element in `new_r[]` and print it (write it to a file). Then do the same thing for all `r[i]`s  which are less than second element in `new_r[]` and print it (write it to a file). And so on up to the last value in `new_r`

How can i do this comparison and calculation?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [something for i in a_range if blabla] syntax

```
for newr in new_r:
  print [(r[i+1]-r[i])**3 * ro[i+1] for i in xrange(len(r) - 1) if r[i] < newr]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
from __future__ import print_function # only for compatibility with the 2 and 3 version of python
r = [0.105, 0.111, 0.218, 0.225, 0.332, 0.440, 0.548, 0.656, 0.865, 1.75]
ro = [850, 856, 844, 830, 787, 826, 764, 773, 781, 748]
new_r = [0.25672, 0.39602, 0.55907, 0.65756, 0.77467, 0.93619]

for el in new_r:
    print("for ",el)
    for i in range(len(r)-1):
        val =  (r[i+1] -r[i])**3*ro[i+1]
        if val < el:
            print(val)
```